# Using pyheif in Windows: Missing _libheif_cffi module

Tags: python, windows, heif

I'm trying to use pyheif in Windows. For that, I've tried following [this solution](https://github.com/carsales/pyheif/issues/2), provided Yienschwen.

It worked so far as I was able to run pip install pyheif without any problem.

However, now, I'm trying to import pyheif, and I get the following error:

[image]

I can't find that file anywhere on the internet...